# Recursion in Matlab vs Java

Tags: java, matlab, recursion

I hacked up a recursive function in Java for a homework problem in my Stats class, that looked something like this:

```
public static int d (int k, int n) {
 if (n == 1) return 1;
 else if (n > k) return 0;
 else return n*d(k-1, n) + n*d(k-1,n-1);
}
```

I then plugged (20, 8) into this function, and got 998,925,952. My professor, however, said that this answer was wrong, and after rethinking my code over and over again, I decided to try the same thing in Matlab:

```
function t = d(k,n)
  t = 0;
  if n == 1
    t = 1;
  elseif n > k
    t = 0;
  else
    t = n*d(k-1, n) + n*d(k-1, n-1);
  end
```

This function, apparently, gave me the right answer with the above input, 6.1169 * 10^17.

This has been bugging me all day, and I have absolutely no idea why two seemingly identical programs in two different languages would give me completely different results.  Can anyone help explain this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Matlab routine is probably working on floating-point input, so it will compute in floating-point.

Your Java routine has integer types; 6.1169e17 is way outside the supported range, so it overflows.  Try changing your types to `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I completely forgot about that! >_<

Comment: For whole numbers it would be better to use a long in Java. All I see above are operations on whole numbers (addition/subtraction and multiplication closed over integers) so it doesn't make sense to use float or double.

Comment: @mwd: Floating-point isn't just about fractions.  The range of `long` is barely much bigger than the OP's desired result.  If he tries a slightly different input parameterisation, `long` will overflow.  `float` or `double` will gracefully scale (well, up to 1e38 and 1e308, respectively).

Comment: But couldn't there be (potentially subtle) issues with precision? I am thinking that a large value wouldn't be left with enough bits in its significand to specify the value exactly. Java also has the BigInteger class.

Comment: Yes, there are precision issues. Even at the current size, 6e17, OP is getting a roundoff error of up to 128. Matlab's `eps` will tell you what the relative precision is around a vlaue; `eps(6e17)` is 128. The Matlab numbers are `double` by default; Java's `double` is exactly the same and switching the type in the Java program should make the results identical. BigInteger would give exact results. Which to use depends on whether you need the precision.

Comment: Actually, I take that back - roundoff error could be a lot more, because that roundoff happens at each step of the calculation, and there are a lot of steps.

Comment: Interesting. I rewrote it to use BigInteger, just to check, and there is no roundoff error here. Both give exactly the same result, `611692004959217280`. I think what's going on is that, in this particular mathematical calculation, there are enough factors of 2 in the multiplications that the result and intermediate values are exactly representable as m*2^n, with n growing fast enough to keep m within the precision of a double's mantissa part. So, even though `double` is an approximate type, this function may give exact results until you overflow double's range.

Answer (score 4):

`611692004959217300` is much larger than `2147483647` which is the integer [MAX_VALUE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in Java.

I got `611692004959217300` by running

```
function d (k, n) {
 if (n == 1) return 1;
 else if (n > k) return 0;
 else return n*d(k-1, n) + n*d(k-1,n-1);
}

console.log(d(20,8));
```

in Firebug.

Comment: +1 Javascript is the language of the future.. Just imagine running MATLAB in the browser :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider what the maximum value an `int` can have, which is what you've got in Java. Now consider what the maximum value a `double` can have, which is MATLAB's default type.

Answer (score 3):

Java integers are 4 bytes in size, so the number looks too big (greater than 2^31). You should try again using "long" or "double" as datatype for your variables.